# In mobile view sliders are not coming properly

Tags: css, css-selectors

In wordpress sliders are coming properly in desktop mode and not coming in mobile mode.

i wan to show full slider in mobile view also.

For reference please find the images and url
http://3.6.131.50/

[image]

[image]

please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Somu N

Comment: .elementor .elementor-hidden-phone {
 display: none;
} This property is hiding you green sections

Answer (score 0):

you used image in first slider so that it does not show properly in mobile, you need to set css for this for mobile view.

```
background-position: left center
```

Comment: not working if you dont mind could you please suggest me where i have to put this above code Minal chauhan

Comment: you can adjust background image setting in elementor  where you are added slide image